# iOS - Resizing images in HTML string

Tags: objective-c, image-resizing

I have a string of HTML that I'm converting into an NSAttributedString like so.

```
NSAttributedString *decodedString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithData:[encodedString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] options:@{NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType, NSCharacterEncodingDocumentAttribute: [NSNumber numberWithInt:NSUTF8StringEncoding]} documentAttributes:nil error:nil];
```

The HTML could have images in it `<img`... - the string changes based on the website your pulling the HTML from.

The images show up in my TextView but are extremely big.

How can I resize all the images (by percent so that they stay the right shape) So that it will fit in my TextView?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just going to give you the core/basic idea to work on it.

--> Use `NSRange` and Search in your `HTML` string, find all the `<img..` tags & make `Substrings`.

--> Now get the `width` and `height` in these substrings of `<img...` tags and Resize your Images `width` and `height` according to your required size and replace these sizes (replace string Values) within the `<img..` tags in `HTML`.

Now make `NSAttributedString` from this updated `HTML` string

Thats it.... :)

This will surely Help You.

Comment: so we have same the logic :D ;)

Comment: NSRange or NSScanner?

Comment: I used nsrange for it